# Correctly computing index for offsetting into frame-resource buffers

Tags: vulkan

Lets say, for a rendering setup, that we have a renderer that can be either double or triple buffered, and this buffering can be changed dynamically, at runtime. So, at any time, it's 2 or 3 frames in flight (FIF).

Frame resources, like buffers, are duplicated to match the FIF-count. Buffers are created large enough to hold (frame-data-size * FIF-count), and reading/writing into those buffers are offsetted accordingly.

For the purpose of offsetting into buffers, is it good enough to use a monotonic clycling index which would go like so:

```
double buffer: 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...
triple buffer: 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, ...
```

Then, if a change is made to the FIF-count a runtime, we first WaitIdle() on the GPU, and then reset this index to 0.

**Is this a safe way of offsetting into buffers, such that we don't trample on data still being used by the GPU?**

I'm particularly unsure how this may play with a triple-buffer setup with a swapchain mailbox present-mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we first WaitIdle() on the GPU, and then reset this index to 0.

Presumably, you're talking about `vkDeviceWaitIdle` (which is a function you should almost never use). If so, then as far as non-swapchain assets are concerned, this is safe. `vkDeviceWaitIdle` will halt the CPU until the GPU device has done all of the work it has been given.

The rules for swapchains don't change just because you waited. You still need to acquire the next image before trying to use it and so forth.

However, waiting doesn't really make sense here. If *all* you do is just reset the index to 0, that means you didn't reallocate any memory. So if you went from 3 buffers to 2, you still have *three buffers* worth of storage, and you're only using two of them.

So what did you wait accomplish? You can just keep cycling through your 3 buffers worth of storage even if you only have 2 swapchain images.

The only point in waiting would be if you need to release storage (or allocate more if you're going from 2 to 3 buffers). And even then, the only reason to wait is if it is absolutely imperative to delete your existing memory before allocating new memory.

Comment: I mentioned the use of `vkDeviceWaitIdle()` just in case, because it happens that the function that handles the FIF-count change invokes `vkDeviceWaitIdle()` in order to recreate the swapchain. That's also the function where the frame index gets reset to 0. My main concern is that the cycling of the frame index, for offsetting into buffers, is guaranteed to work in the setup I described.

Comment: @Dess: "*the function that handles the FIF-count change invokes `vkDeviceWaitIdle()` in order to recreate the swapchain*" You don't have to do that. It is perfectly valid to retire a swapchain while the device is in use. If you have acquired a swapchain image when you recreate the swapchain, it will still be available for presentation.

Comment: *"It is perfectly valid to retire a swapchain while the device is in use."* That's very interesting, even if counter-intuitive.